# How to ingest multiple Sensors Data into AWS Timestream using Iot Core Rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I know that if I send all the sensors separately I can use the replacement models ${} to assign the type, however, I would like to be able to send all the sensors at the same time, because it is much more efficient from the point of view of AWS cost, is there a way to do this?

I can already inject data into the timestream using rules, having a payload like this:

```
{ "id": 1325, "Sensors":{ "1": 40.5, "2": 99.3, "40": 1001.0 }, Timestamp: 1689630611 }
```

Using a sql statement:

```
select Sensors.*
```

and inside a dimensions, im use:

```
id: ${id}
time: ${Timestamp}
```

Its works well, each sensor is saved on Timestream this way:

```
{"id": 1325, "measure_name": "1", measure_value": 40.5},
{"id": 1325, "measure_name": "2", measure_value": 99.3},
{"id": 1325, "measure_name": "40", measure_value": 1001.0}
```

In addition to saving the sensor name, I would like to include a dimension with the sensor type to be able to use the scheduled queries feature more efficiently, but I haven't found a way to assign the type of each sensor separately using a dimension, here an example of what the payload would look like:

```
{
  "InstallationInstanceId": 1325,
  "Sensors": [
    { "id": 1, "type": 3, "value": 40.5 },
    { "id": 2, "type": 4, "value": 99.3 },
    { "id": 40, "type": 7, "value": 1001.0 }
  ]
}
```

and something like this should be saved in the timestream

```
{"id": 1325, "measure_name": "1", measure_value": 40.5, "measure_type": 3},
{"id": 1325, "measure_name": "2", measure_value": 99.3, "measure_type": 4}, 
{"id": 1325, "measure_name": "40", measure_value": 1001.0, "measure_type": 7}
```